# How to design blog templates

Tags: weblogic, blogs, blogger

I would like to design my blog. I don't know, the tool is having or not. Suppose anything have like that means pls help me and say the best and user friendly tool.(Offline tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really broad question but I have had good experiences with both:

BlogDesk - http://www.blogdesk.org/en/index.htm

and

Windows Live Writer - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8621

Both are free and can be used offline. Do you have any specific requirements for what the software can do?

Comment: Shall i import my previous template and can edit that?

Comment: Yes you should be able to do the import.